# Pass in arrays for x and y values to use in pie Chart in MVC?

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, charts

Using the built-in [Chart in Web Helpers](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_chart.asp), I was able to bind my data to build a chart, but only if it was a bar chart. I want to make a pie chart. Every example shows creating an array for x and y values by hard-coding them. For example,

```
       xValue: new[] {  "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" }, 
       yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
```

I went through probably the longest way possible to get my information set up in two arrays and it isn't working. There is no error, it just displays a white screen. When debugging, the values come through just as expected. Here is my controller:

```
 var query = string.Format("Select C.* from Cards C Left Join CardDecks CD ON CD.CardID = C.CardID Where DeckID = {0}", id);
 var cardlist = db.Cards.SqlQuery(query).ToList();
 var piearray = cardlist.Select(t => t.MainType.Title).ToList();
 var pievalues = piearray.GroupBy(c => c, (a, b) => string.Format("{0} {1}", b.Count(), a)).ToArray();
            string first = " ";
            string second = " ";
            string xvalues = " ";
            string yvalues = " ";
            List<String> xx = new List<string>();
            List<String> yy = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in pievalues)
            {
                first = item.ToString().Substring(0, item.IndexOf(" "));
                second = item.ToString().Substring(item.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
                xx.Add(first);
                yy.Add(second);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < xx.Count; i++)
            {

                if (i == xx.Count - 1)
                {
                    xvalues = xvalues + xx[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    xvalues = xvalues + xx[i] + " , ";
                }

            }
            string[] XValue = xvalues.Split(',');

            for (int i = 0; i < yy.Count; i++)
            {

                if (i == yy.Count - 1)
                {
                    yvalues = yvalues + yy[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    yvalues = yvalues + yy[i] + " , ";
                }

            }
            string[] YValue = yvalues.Split(',');
            var myChart = new Chart(width: 200, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(chartType: "Pie", xValue: XValue, xField: "X Field",
            yValues: YValue , yFields: "Y Fields").Write();
            var vm = new ViewDeck();
            vm.Chart = myChart;  
            //More vm.views = view
            return View(vm);
```

Here is part of my Model:

```
public Chart Chart { get; set; }
```

Here is part of my View:

```
@Model.Chart
```

I would like to avoid using 3rd party plug-ins. Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing to HighCharts... after I finally got this working it turned out that it looked horrible and there wasn't much in the way of styling. I have some if statements to check the number in the array, it's the only way I found I could build the pie chart objects. It is a bit different when using line or bar charts because you can copy x and y values independently. In the pie chart structure, you have to build new object [] with the string name and int number. If you knew how many categories you were going to have and just needed the numbers to be dynamic you don't have to worry about an array count. Here is an example with array count:

```
if (arrayCount == 3)
            {
                Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
                   .InitChart(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Chart { PlotShadow = false })
                   .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Card Type Distribution" })
                    .SetSeries(new Series
                    {
                        Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                        Data = new Data(new object[]
                    {

                        new object[] { XValue[0], YValue[0] }, 
                        new object[] { XValue[1], YValue[1] },
                         new object[] { XValue[2], YValue[2]}
                    })

                    });
```